# Populating dropdown menu with JSON Data in Mvc views

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i am a beginner when it comes to javascript(Json). i am trying to populate a dropdown box based on the selection of another dropdown. as you can see in the image below as an example i am trying to populate the " Rule Choice " dropdown based on the "Product template" dropdown. the attempted code is also available.

Any Help would be appreciated.

thank you

```
function drFilter()
{
    var productTemp = $('#ddlProdTemp :selected').val();
    $.getJSON('ptdrFilter', { productTemplate: productTemp }, function (result) {
        var ddl = $('#ddl2');
        var length = result.length;
        ddl.empty();
        if (length > 0) {

            $(document.createElement('option'))
           .attr('value', 0)
           .text("-- Please Select --")
           .appendTo(ddl);
        }

        $(result).each(function (will) {
            //
            $(document.createElement('option'))
                .attr('value', result[will])
                .text(result[will])
                .appendTo(ddl);
        });
    });
}


 public ActionResult ptdrFilter(int id)
    {
        IUnitOfWork uow = DataAccess.GetUnitOfWork();
        using (ManageProductTemplate ptLogic = new ManageProductTemplate(ref uow))
        {
            List<ProductTemplate> currentpt = ptLogic.GetBy(x => x.ProductTemplateID == id);
            List<string> pt = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in currentpt)
            {
                pt.Add(item.DistributionRule.Name);

            }
            return Json(pt);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show what your result contains  , console.log(result) ; and check your console then I will be able to give you some help :)

Comment: i have added the method, however the console does not appear anywhere i have also updated the code with the controller if that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="main">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>

    <select id="subselect"></select>

    <script>
        var sampleData = { a: { value1: "text 1 in a", value2: "text 2 in a" }, b: { value1: "text 1 in b", value2: "text 2 in b" } };
        var dataInJSONForm = JSON.stringify(sampleData);
        var datainJSObjectForm = JSON.parse(dataInJSONForm);

        $('#main').on('change', function (e) {
            var valueChosenInMain = $(this).val();
            var options = datainJSObjectForm[valueChosenInMain];

            var $subselect = $('#subselect');
            $subselect.children().detach();
            for (var property in options) {
                $subselect.append($('<option>', { value: property, text: options[property] }));
            }   
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```